# facebook-unity-sdk: AppRequest Questions

Tags: apprequests, facebook-app-requests, facebook-unity-sdk

**Questions**

1. When sending an AppRequest, my friends list that comes up on iOS always has 48 users in it even when I have 300+ friends. Is there a way to change this limit for high-end devices that have plenty of memory?
2. How does FB decide which 48 friends to show in the AppRequest dialog? It doesn't appear to be my first 48 friends alphabetically
3. The "Title" parameter of the AppRequest call doesn't get used. Even in the InteractiveConsole, I set the title to "Invite Friends" and the title always says "App Requests". Is this just broken or am I confused?

Edit: I know there is a maxRecipients param but my understanding is that only determines how many total can be SENT at once, not how many friends display. I have the maxRecipients set at 500 and it still only shows 48 friends in the list.

**Info**
Unity version: 4.3.0f4
FB SDK version: 4.3.4
FB Build version: 131022.2bb3e6026790434

Answer (score 2):

Right now there's no way to change the number of users who come up in that selector. They're chosen according to Facebook's estimate of how likely they are to be interested in, and interact with, an apprequest.

I believe that the issue with the title may be a bug. I'm investigating that now; could you please file a bug in the FB developer bug tool, and post the URL here, to help with that?

Comment: Thanks Colin. Here's the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1434196736792085